# Angular 11 two way binding for a numeric field: backspace not working as expected and giving junk values whenever pressed

Tags: angular, angular11, backspace, two-way-binding, numeric-input

I am working with Angular 11 and came across two way binding for quantity field which is an input field of the type number. Problem arrives when I try to use backspace for the quantity field input. It gives junk values which are then displayed with the correct value.

.html file

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" (click)="addProductToCart(product,1)">
<i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
<input type="number" [ngModel]="product.quantity" (ngModelChange)="addProductToCart(product,$event)" id="prod-qty">
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" (click)="addProductToCart(product,-1)">
<i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i></button>
```

.ts file

```
addProductToCart(pr: any, q: any){
    pr.quantity=pr.quantity+Number(q);
 }
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?? Please do let me know

Comment: Did it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two ways binding: `[(ngModel)]="binding"`.

Your input should be:

```html
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.quantity" id="prod-qty">
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but the issue occurs when I click on backspace. It randomly loads a junk value whenever I click on it.

Comment: You need to remove `(ngModelChange)="addProductToCart(product,$event)"` from your input as I did in my answer.

Comment: It's working now after I removed the addProductToCart(product,$event) method. Thank you